# Como retornar 2 objetos ao mesmo tempo em um método em Java?

Tags: java, método

```
 public class Equacao2Grau {

        int a, b, c;

        public int CalculoDelta(){

            return (int) (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);
        }

        public int FormulaQuadratica(){
            int x1 = (int) (-b + Math.sqrt(CalculoDelta()) / 2*a);

            int x2 = (int) (-b - Math.sqrt(CalculoDelta()) / 2*a);

            return x1, x2;
        }

        public String exibeResultado(){

            return "X1 = " + this.FormulaQuadratica() + "\nX2 = " + this.FormulaQuadratica();
        }
    }
```

Comment: pq não retorna um array/lista ou até mesmo um objeto?

Comment: Cara  Concatena os retornos separados por ; e depois retira por possições
        public int FormulaQuadratica(){
            int x1 = (int) (-b + Math.sqrt(CalculoDelta()) / 2*a);

            int x2 = (int) (-b - Math.sqrt(CalculoDelta()) / 2*a);
            String retorno = x1 + ";" + x2;
            return retorno;
        }

Depois da um Split(';') e apresenta colocando a posição variavel[1]

Comment: @RenanSilveira Não tem necessidade disso. Se for assim é melhor retornar um `array`.

Comment: Uma tupla, `javafx.util.Pair`, pode resolver. Pode criar um tipo com propriedades `x1` e `x2` também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode retornar alguma estrutura de dados que satisfaça o seu problema:

```
public class Equacao2Grau {

  int a, b, c;

  public int CalculoDelta() {

    return (int) (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c);
  }

  public Map<String, Integer> FormulaQuadratica() {
    Map<String, Integer> resultado = new HashMap<>();
    int x1 = (int) (-b + Math.sqrt(CalculoDelta()) / 2 * a);

    int x2 = (int) (-b - Math.sqrt(CalculoDelta()) / 2 * a);

    resultado.put("x1", x1);
    resultado.put("x2", x2);

    return resultado;
  }

  public String exibeResultado() {
    Map<String, Integer> resultado = this.FormulaQuadratica();

    return "X1 = " + resultado.get("x1") + "\nX2 = " + resultado.get("x2");
  }
}
```

O `Map` permite que você "nomeie" o resultado a partir das chaves.

Comment: Acho que o que ele quer é um `Set`: um conjunto de valores únicos e não-repetidos, sem uma ordem específica.